# Поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: python, строки

Нужно найти в строке: входит ли данная строчка в строку или нет. например, есть строка 
`sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe` нужно узнать входит ли в нее `dff` или нет.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if "dff" in "sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe":
    print u"Входит!"
```

Comment: опередил на 4 секунды=)

Comment: а если нужно узнать с какой позиции входит?

Comment: в комментариях нельзя оформлять красиво код?

    try:
        index = s1.index("dff")
    except ValueError:
        print "substring not found"

Comment: использовать метод `find`.
 
    s1 = "sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe"
    index = s1.find('dff')

Этот код делает ровно то же самое, что и в ответе ниже, но выглядит опрятнее, т.к. оно без вложенности.

Comment: полностью согласен.

Comment: а если надо или или  то можно так ?   ` if "dff" or "svv" in "sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe":`

Comment: if "a" in s or "b" in s:

Answer (score 4):

https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html
Это ссылка на сайт, где все есть. А так можно посчитать количество вхождений:

```
S1 = 'sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe'
S2 = 'dff'
Count = S1.count(S2)
if Count == 0:
    print('Не входит')
else:
    print('Входит')
```

Если что - S.count(str) - это функция, которая считает количество вхождений str в S

Comment: то что надо))))

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью множеств, например при чтении с файла пропускать строки, в которые входит определенное слово:

```
ignore = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']

with open(file,"r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not (set(ignore) & set(line.split())):
            print(line, end="")
```

Comment: ваш код пытается напечатать строки из файла, которые не содержат слова, разделённые пробелом, из заданного списка ignore (`grep -vwFf ignore file`). Этот код не ищет подстроку в строке. [Связанный вопрос о том как задачу в ответе эффективно реализовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно найти слово в строке с % вероятностью вот ссылка:
https://github.com/AndreSci/Find-word-in-string-percent/blob/main/Percent_text_find.py

line_1 - слово которое ищешь.
line_2 - где ищешь.
100 - это вероятное совпадения.

```
def find_word_per(line_1, line_2, percent=100):
max_found = 0

for item_1 in range(len(line_1)):

    for item_2 in range(len(line_2)):
        index_found = 0

        if line_1[item_1] == line_2[item_2]:

            for index in range(len(line_2) - item_2):
                if item_1 + index >= len(line_1):
                    break
                elif line_1[item_1 + index] == line_2[item_2 + index]:
                    index_found += 1
        if max_found < index_found:
            max_found = index_found

result_per = (100 / len(line_1)) * max_found

return result_per >= percent
```

Может кому поможет, мою проблему решил.

Comment: Это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос

Comment: Добавил сюда так-как меня поисковики часто сюда бросали.

Comment: Лучше не добавлять ответ не подходящий под вопрос, а добавить отдельный вопрос с подробным описанием проблемы (сейчас не очень очевидно, что такое совпадение с вероятностью) и своим ответом. И возможно вам еще добавят другие варианты ответов.

Comment: почему не подходящий? test_find("dff", "sdfssf sddff svvsef xbsdf sdfwwe", 100)  # True

Comment: Потому что в вопросе нужно просто определить, есть ли подстрока в строке. Это решается одним выражением (через in). У вас какая-то другая проблема. Предположим, у кого-то будет похожая проблема, но он на свой вопрос не найдет ответ, потому что ваш ответ не под вопросом с подробным описанием именно вашей проблемы (который будет проиндексирован поисковиками), а где-то под вопросом с совсем другой проблемой.

Comment: Технически, возможно ваш код и может решать проблему из вопроса, но для такой простой проблемы он слишком переусложнен.

Comment: Рекомендуете создать новую тему с своим решение? И еще раз добавил сюда свой ответ из-за поисковиков.

Comment: Тут нет тем, есть вопросы и ответы. Да, рекомендую создать вопрос и добавить ему свой ответ. То что пришли на этот вопрос из поисковиков это еще не значит, что ваш код подходит под вопрос.