# Поиск повторяющихся строк

Tags: python, grep, perl, awk, linux

Привет.

Возник вопрос:
Есть файл 1 ~ 2GB 
и есть файл 2 ~ 1MB

Вопрос - как наиболее быстро подсчитать кол-во вхождений строк из файла2 в файле1?

К примеру файл1:

```
Тест корова большая
Флагман большая корова
Трубадур золотистый
Флагманский телефон N90
Логическое оформление Тест корова
Бла бла стар
```

Файл2:

```
Трубадур
Тест корова
телефон
```

Должно получиться:

```
Трубадур 1
Тест корова 2
телефон 1
```

Файл 1 много больше файл2.

Comment: @Titano, Вас интересует точное вхождение (с лидирующими и конечными пробелами и т.п.) или нужно учитывать разбивку строк файлов  на слова?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Эффективным методом поиска нескольких подстрок одновременно в большом тексте является [алгоритм Ахо-Корасика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA). Оригинальный fgrep (grep -F) использует этот алгоритм. GNU grep в этом случае использует Commentz-Walter алгоритм (объединение Ахо-Корасика и [алгоритма поиска строки Бойера—Мура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)). ripgrep (rg) иногда работает быстрее GNU grep, используя [SIMD алгоритм, называемый Teddy](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/blob/30e35a37b2101d5e6367509709ce1140f1ba123c/src/simd_accel/teddy128.rs) -- см. [ripgrep is faster than {grep, ag, git grep, ucg, pt, sift}](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

Чтобы подсчитать найденные строки, можно использовать `sort | uniq -c` команду, предложенную @BOPOH в комментарии к вопросу. Ещё можно использовать словарь вместо сортировки:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -Fof file2 file1 |
perl -lne '$seen{$_}++ }{ while (my ($k,$v)=each %seen){print "$k $v"}'
```

Измерения могут показать, какая из команд (`sort+uniq` или `perl`) быстрее в данном случае.

Для сравнения можно посмотреть, сколько займёт Питон-скрипт *без* использования дополнительных пакетов (например, `esm`), которые реализуют Ахо-Корасик-подобные алгоритмы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter

def main():
    # load substrings from file2
    with open('file2', 'rb') as file2:
        substrings = {line.strip() for line in file2} # unique lines
        substrings = filter(None, substrings) # filter blank lines
        substrings = sorted(substrings, key=len, reverse=True) # longest first
        pattern = b"|".join(map(re.escape, substrings))
        find_substrings = re.compile(pattern).findall

    # count substrings in file1
    counter = Counter()
    counter_update = counter.update # cache the lookup (for CPython)
    with open('file1', 'rb') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            counter_update(find_substrings(line))

    # write substrings frequencies
    write = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write
    for substring, count in counter.most_common(): # most common first
        write(substring)
        write(b' ')
        write(str(count).encode())
        write(b'\n')

main()
```

#### Результат

```
Тест корова 2
телефон 1
Трубадур 1
```

Вот ещё вариант для сравнения, где строки в файле ищутся с помощью регулярного выражения и `mmap`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap
from operator import methodcaller

def generate_tokens(filename, pattern):
    with open(filename) as f, mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as mm:
         yield from re.finditer(pattern, mm)

def main():
    # load substrings from file2
    with open('file2', 'rb') as file2:
        substrings = {line.strip() for line in file2} # unique lines
        substrings = filter(None, substrings) # filter blank lines
        substrings = sorted(substrings, key=len, reverse=True) # longest first
        pattern = b"|".join(map(re.escape, substrings))

    # count substrings in file1
    file1_substrings = generate_tokens('file1', pattern)
    counter = Counter(map(methodcaller('group'), file1_substrings))

    # write substrings frequencies
    write = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write
    for substring, count in counter.most_common(): # most common first
        write(substring)
        write(b' ')
        write(str(count).encode())
        write(b'\n')

main()
```

Работает на Windows, *nix. Код для Питон 3, но его можно легко адаптировать для Питон 2, если необходимо.

Comment: Ух ты, спасибо!

Вариант "влоб" - по примерный расчетом займет ~ 20часов. (перебор)
Вариант без пакетов ~ в 2 раза меньше
Вариант с `grep -F` на файле ~5GB с ключевыми словами ~ на 4MB заняло:
real    2m54.014s
user    2m53.995s
sys     0m2.652s

Comment: Да, grep хорош (~30MB/sec это впечатляет).

Интересно, сколько памяти ушло там под бор из алгоритма Ахо-Корасика?

@Titano,  насколько правильно сопоставление, скажем, образца *телефон* с текстом *микротелефонов*?

Comment: Памяти не скажу - но не почувствовалось.
Насчет сопоставления тоже, т.к. было строгое соответствие, т.е. `телефон` и `микротелефон` такой комбинации не может быть (это другая задача сбора информации).

И забыл - это скорость на сервере с SSD.
Если есть интерес, проведу тест на HDD.

Comment: @Titano: Я добавил решение, использующее `mmap`. Оно может быть быстрее, если строки из file2 очень редко встречаются в file1.

Answer (score 5):

Решение "в лоб" (сомневаюсь, что будет быстро)))

```
grep -o -f file2 file1 | sort | uniq -c
```

5 строк в file2 и 2.7Г в file1 где-то за 4 минуты обработало.

Если не требуется для каждой отдельной строки количество считать (т.е. достаточно общего количества), тогда можно еще проще (и немного быстрее):

```
grep -co -f file2 file1
```

Comment: в file1 лежит строка
в file2 лежит подстрока

и надо посчитать, сколько раз на строках файла1 встретилась подстрока

Answer (score 2):

Ну, как вариант, можно попробовать вот так в лоб:

```
somelist1 = []  
somelist2 = []  
f1 = open('file1.txt')  # файл на 2mb
f2 = open('file2.txt')  # файл на 2gb

for line in f1:
    a1 = line.replace('\n', '')
    somevar = a1.split()
    for i in somevar:
        somelist1.append(i)

for line in f2:
    a2 = line.replace('\n', '')
    somevar = a2.split()
    for i in somevar:
        somelist2.append(i)

for i in somelist1:
    index = 0
    for j in somelist2:
        if i == j:
            index += 1
    print(i + " - " + str(index))
```

Вывод в виде:

```
Трубадур - 481779
Тест - 963549
корова - 1445337
телефон - 481779
```

Попробовал на файле в 150 мб, сделался за 5-7 секунд, время не замерял. Может, кто-то предложит более оптимизированное решение.

**UPDATE**

Попробовал на файле побольше, 2gb скорее всего точно не прогрузить, этот вариант применим только к небольшим файлам.

Comment: IMHO это не совсем то, что спрашивают в вопросе.

Вы подсчитываете сколько раз каждое слово из  f1 встретилось в f2.  
(кстати, а что это за таинственная str(index)? )

А в вопросе просят искать вхождения **строки** f1 в f2.

--

Про то, поместится ли 2Gb файл в память в питоне -- я вообще молчу.

Comment: Возможно.
Если искать именно вхождение строки это меняется одной строчкой.
"(кстати, а что это за таинственная str(index)? )" а Вы как конкатенируете строку с числом? (не используя плейсхолдеры и формат)
Вы всегда вправе предложить свое решение, к сожалению пока его не вижу :(

Comment: Имеется ввиду строка. Но думаю, это не принципиально.  
Перл, питон, пхп прекрасно и 4гб принимают.

Думаю, надо параллелить, т.к. двойного цикла не избежать(?)