# Как найти слово?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()  
{  
    char mass [80][80];  
    char slovo[80];  
    int i=0;  
    int a,k=0;  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
    FILE *f;  
    f=fopen("text.txt", "r");  
    if(f==NULL) printf("файл text.txt не открыт\n");

    a=i;  
    printf("Введите слово для поиска: ");  
    // Здесь должен быть линейный поиск  
}
```

Comment: кому не ясна суть вопроса, посмотрите на ответы, если ответы не ясны, оставьте комментарий под соответствующим ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот ответ, разбирайтесь:

```
#include "iostream"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    ifstream file("C://1.txt"); // открыли файл с текстом
    string s, find;
    char c;

    while (!file.eof()){  // прочитали его и заполнили им строку
        file.get(c);
        s.push_back(c);
    }

    file.close(); // обязательно закрыли

    cout << "enter a world for find: ";
    cin >> find;

    int pos = s.find(find); // поиск

    if (pos == -1)
        cout << "not finded" << endl;
    else
        cout << "finded in " << pos << " simvol position" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь разобрался.

Comment: Данный код ищет подстроку, а не слово в файле, т.е., он найдёт "фон" если файл содержит "телефон", хотя самого слова "фон" в файле может и не быть.

Необходимо проверять на ошибки после `file.get(c)`, в противном случае можно мусор записать в `s` строку. Вот [рабочий способ считывания файла в строку целиком](http://hashcode.ru/questions/380085#380361).

Можно ещё упомянуть, что необходимо изменить код, чтобы можно было передать Юникодные имена файлов и входное слово для поиска на Винде.

Comment: @jfs счас подумал, можно добавить пару пробелов по обеим концам, чтоб слово полностью совпало, это несложно и загружать можно тоже по словам, ориентируясь по пробелам

Comment: @perfect добавить вокруг слова пробелы не достаточно, если слово находится в начале, конце файла или если слова разделены одним из других шести стандартных пробельных символов: `" \t\n\r\f\v"` (наиболее вероятно новой строкой `'\n'`).

Answer (score 5):

`istream_iterator<string>` + `find` алгоритм являются простым способом определить, содержит ли файл, данное отделённое пробелами слово, используя линейный поиск:

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
istream_iterator<string> eof;
bool found = find(istream_iterator<string>(file), eof, word) != eof;
```

Например, если слово задано с коммандной строки, а файл передаётся на стандартном вводе:

```
/** $ g++ *.cxx -o find-word && <input.txt ./find-word word

    Exit status:

      0 -- found word
      1 -- not found
      2 -- error
*/
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  if (argc != 2) {
    cerr << "Usage: find-word WORD <input.txt\n";
    exit(2);
  }
  string word(argv[1]); // word to search
  istream_iterator<string> words(cin), eof; 
  bool found = find(words, eof, word) != eof;
  return found ? 0 : (cin.eof() ? 1 : 2);
}
```

Поиск работает, потому что `istream_iterator<string>` вызывает `cin >> next_word` внутри, который пропускает пробелы по умолчанию (`skipws` флаг установлен) и `find` алгоритм затем просто сравнивает `next_word == word`.

Что такое пробел, а значит и что такое слово может зависеть от текущей локали.

На системах с utf-8 локалью, код работает как есть с произвольным Юникодным текстом  (поддержка нескольких языков в одном документе, поддержка эмотиконов и т.д., правда Юникодные пробелы не распознаются). Windows может испортить входной поток за счёт неявных (codepage) преобразований байтового потока -- как прочитать Юникодный текст на Windows лучше задать как отдельный вопрос.

Код читает только одно слово за раз и возвращается как только входное слово обнаружено, то есть код может работать с очень большими файлами и если заданное слово присутствует во вводе, то программа может вернуться раньше -- без считывания всего ввода. Код также информирует об ошибках ввода (`cin.eof()` тест).

Существует множество [строковых алгоритмов, которые помогают найти подстроку в строке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8), например, [алгоритм Ахо—Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA) (мог быть использован для реализации `fgrep`) может быть эффективнее в некоторых случаях чем наивный линейный поиск. Связанный вопрос: [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044).

Comment: Ответ ичерпывающий и точный. Давно уж пора создать предмет как философия программирования, в коем вы были бы, не побоюсь этого слова гуру.

Answer (score 4):

Читайте в цикле файл по словам функцией `fscanf()` и используйте `strcmp()` для сравнения.

--

См. `man fscanf`. Что будет непонятно -- спрашивайте.

**Update**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int 
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
  FILE *fp;
  const char *fname;
  int rc = 1;  // like grep return code

  if (!(fp = fopen(fname = (argv[1] ? argv[1]: "1.txt"),"r"))) {
    perror(fname);
    exit(2);
  }

  char input[81], word[81];
  printf("Enter word: "); fflush(stdout);
  if (scanf("%80s", input) == 1) {
    printf("search [%s] in %s\n", input, fname);
    while(fscanf(fp, "%80s", word) == 1)
      if (strcmp(word, input) == 0) {
        rc = 0; 
        printf("Found in pos: %ld\n", ftell(fp));
      }
  } else
    puts("nothing to search");

  return rc;
}
```

Windows 7, emacs e-shell:

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ b.cpp -o b
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./b
Enter word: ERRDEMO
search [ERRDEMO] in 1.txt
Found in pos: 591
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: Я воспользовался вашим советом.  Но в отместку появилась иная проблема, как задать массив, чтобы в него влез весь текст txt в 500 кб. При попытке скомпилировать, ругается. Собственно, вот мой код:

int main()  
{  
    char mass [100][100];<-- как задать массив, чтобы поместился весь текст?  
    char slovo[80];  
    int i=0;  
    int a,k=0;  
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
FILE *f;  
f=fopen("text.txt", "r");  
if(f==NULL) printf("файл text.txt не открыт\n");  
 
while(!feof(f))  
{  
     fscanf(f,"%s",&mass[i]);  
     printf("%s\n", mass[i]);  
     i++;
}  

// написал поиск  

}

Comment: Используйте лучше тип string для загрузки текста в оперативную память, а потом ищите строку в подстроке http://hashcode.ru/questions/107089/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @АльфаЧ, а зачем читать в массив весь текст?

    char word[80], slovo[80];
    FILE *f = fopen(...);
    ...
    while (fscanf(f, "%s", word) == 1)
       if (strcmp(word, slovo) == 0) {
         puts("Found");
         break; // или чего Вы хотите делать с этом словом
       }

вот и все.

Comment: Читать в массив текст нужно для того, чтобы произвести линейный поиск. С размерами файла, к примеру, 80 слов, поиск работает, если текст увеличить до 500 Кб, программа отказывается работать.

Comment: @АльфаЧ, думаю, проблема у Вас в чем-то другом.

Кстати, что значит -- *отказывается работать*?

Опишите подробно все симптомы, сообщения на экране и т.п. (я-то  даром ясновиденья обладаю не в полной степени).

--

Попробуйте мой фрагмент с файлом любого размера.

(если опять не работает -- положите код куда-нибудь (например на pastebin.com))

Comment: Отказывался работать, когда я выводил на экран весь текст, по вашему совету, я убрал выведения массива на экран. Теперь у меня не работает поиск. Я ввожу слово (оно там есть), выводится на экран, "слово не найдено". Мне лишь бы понять вот что, если я увеличу в char mass[100][100]<-- эти значения, выходит ошибка, мол, размер массива превышает допустимый. Ведь если текст у меня состоит из 100 слов, программа работает корректно, размер напрямую зависит от char mass [100][100].

Comment: @АльфаЧ, еще раз **прямо говорю**, для *линейного поиска* слова в файле **не надо читать его целиком в память**.

Читаете файл по одному слову и сравниваете с заданным.

--

Не понимаю, что именно тут непонятно?  
(сейчас обновлю ответ примером)

Comment: Весьма благодарен за советы.

Comment: Вместо `argv[1] ?`, нужно `argc > 1 ?` написать, чтобы избежать UB. Нет необходимости `fname` присваивание внутрь `fopen()` запихивать.

В 2014 году не хорошо жёстко записывать ограничения, такие как `80s`. То есть либо нужно динамически под текущее слово память выделять, например, как [в моём ответе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/384287#384839), либо использовать алгоритм, который умеет сравнивать слово по частям (можно даже по одному байту читать `getchar()`).

Следует также упомянуть, что данный код может иметь проблемы с Юникодом на Винде (имя файла, само входное слово).

Comment: @jfs, в винде вообще столько проблем, что лучше от нее держаться подальше (хотя данный код в ней (локализованной для cp1251) иногда (ascii или эмулятор терминала, работающий в cp1251) работает).

Что касается систем с UB для `av[1]` (я, правда, таких не знаю), то IMHO их лучше явно выделять, используя `#ifdef`.

Что же касается %80s, то не стал я грузить автора %m вместе с освобождением динамического буфера или какой-нибудь `get_word_file()` использующей внутри `getline()` и возвращающей указатель и длину (нет смысла как для примера,  так и для кучи практических приложений (даже в 2015 году))