# Поиск слова из файла

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Требовалось найти введенное с клавиатуры слово в файле и вывести его позицию (позиции - если найдено несколько). Написал данную функцию, однако как бы я не пытался избежать этого, но на местах, где подряд идут точки и пробелы, счетчик слов сбивается. Прошу помощи.

```
void search (FILE* file, char t[20], char *x, unsigned size) {
    unsigned a=0, k=0, max=0, i=0, j=0;
    while ((x[i]=fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        ++i;
    max=strlen(t);
    for (i=0; i<(size-1); ++i) {
        if (((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]=='\n') || (x[i+1]==EOF)) && (i != (size-2)) && ( (x[i+2] != ' ') || (x[i+2] != EOF) || (x[i+2] != '.') || (x[i+2] != ',') ))
            ++j;
        if (t[k]==x[i]) {
            ++k;
            if ((k==max) && ((x[i-max]==' ') || (x[i-max])==',' || (x[i-max]=='.')) && ((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]==EOF) || (x[i+1]=='\n')) && ((x[i+2] != ' ') || (x[i+2] != EOF) || (x[i+2] != '.') || (x[i+2] != ','))) {
            printf("%d ", j);
            ++a;
            }
        }
    }
    if (a==0)
        printf("Not found.");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: похожий вопрос (но для c++): [Как найти слово?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384287/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил я свое решение. Вот что получилось:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned maxlength (FILE* file, char *x);
void correction (char *x, unsigned size, unsigned max);
void search (FILE* file, char t[20], char *x, unsigned size);
void searchwo(FILE* file, char t[20], char *x, unsigned size);

int main()
{
FILE *myfile;
char *text, word[20];
unsigned k, size, max, i, j;
while (k != 3) {
    printf("Please, select action: \n 1) Correction \n 2) Search \n 3) Exit \n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    switch (k) {
        case 1: myfile = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
                fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_END);
                size = ftell(myfile);
                rewind(myfile);
                text=(char*) malloc(size);
                max=maxlength(myfile, text);
                fclose(myfile);
                myfile = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
                correction(text, size, max);
                for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
                    fputc(text[i], myfile);
                fclose(myfile);
                free(text);
                break;
        case 2: myfile = fopen ("output.txt", "r");
                fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_END);
                size = ftell(myfile);
                rewind(myfile);
                text=(char*) malloc(size);
                printf("Enter a word... \n");
                scanf("%s", word);
                printf("1) With register \n2) W\\o register \n");
                scanf("%d", &j);
                switch (j) {
                    case 1: search(myfile, word, text, size);
                            break;
                    case 2: searchwo(myfile, word, text, size);
                }
                free(text);
                fclose(myfile);
                break;
        default: printf("Press any key... \n");
    }
}
return 0;
}

unsigned maxlength (FILE* file, char *x) {
unsigned i=0, k=0, max=0;
while ((x[i] = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if ((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != '\n'))
        ++k;
    else
        k=0;
    if (k>max)
        max=k;
    ++i;
}
return max;
}

void correction (char *x, unsigned size, unsigned max) {
unsigned k=0, i=0;
if ((x[i]<123) && (x[i]>96))
    printf("%c", x[0]=x[0]-32);
else printf("%c", x[0]);
for (i=1; i<size; ++i) {
    ++k;
    if (x[i-4]!='.' && x[i-2]=='.' && ((x[i-1]==' ') || (x[i-1]=='\n')) && (x[i]<123) && (x[i]>96))
        printf("%c", x[i]=x[i]-32);
    else
        if ((x[i]==' ') && (k>(120-max))) {
            printf("\n");
            k=0;
        }
        else
            printf("%c", x[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}

void search (FILE* file, char t[20], char *x, unsigned size) {
unsigned a=0, k=0, max=0, i=0, j=0;
max=strlen(t);
printf("dlina = %d \n", max);
for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
    x[i]=fgetc(file);
for (i=0; i<size; ++i){
    if (((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != ',') && (x[i] != '.') && (x[i] != '\n') && (x[i] != EOF)) && ((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]=='\n') || (x[i+1]==EOF) || (x[i+1]==','))) {
        ++j;
    }
    if (t[k]==x[i])
        ++k;
    if (k==max && ((i-max)==-1 || x[i-max]==' ') && (x[i+1]==',' || x[i+1]==' ' || x[i+1]=='.')) {
        printf("%d ", j);
        ++a;
        k=0;
    }
    if (((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != ',') && (x[i] != '.') && (x[i] != '\n') && (x[i] != EOF)) && ((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]=='\n') || (x[i+1]==EOF) || (x[i+1]==',')))
        k=0;
}
if (a==0)
    printf("Not found");
printf("\n");
}

void searchwo(FILE* file, char t[20], char *x, unsigned size) {
unsigned a=0, k=0, max=0, i=0, j=0;
max=strlen(t);
printf("dlina = %d \n", max);
for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
    x[i]=fgetc(file);
for (i=0; i<size; ++i){
    if (((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != ',') && (x[i] != '.') && (x[i] != '\n') && (x[i] != EOF)) && ((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]=='\n') || (x[i+1]==EOF) || (x[i+1]==','))) {
        ++j;
    }
    if (t[k]==x[i] || t[k]==x[i]-32 || t[k]==x[i]+32)
        ++k;
    if (k==max && ((i-max)==-1 || x[i-max]==' ') && (x[i+1]==',' || x[i+1]==' ' || x[i+1]=='.')) {
        printf("%d ", j);
        ++a;
        k=0;
    }
    if (((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != ',') && (x[i] != '.') && (x[i] != '\n') && (x[i] != EOF)) && ((x[i+1]==' ') || (x[i+1]=='.') || (x[i+1]=='\n') || (x[i+1]==EOF) || (x[i+1]==',')))
        k=0;
}
if (a==0)
    printf("Not found");
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: публикование всего кода (относящегося и неотносящегося к вопросу) без объяснений не является хорошим ответом. Расскажите словами, в чём была проблема кода в вопросе и как именно ваш код её разрешил.

Answer (score 2):

Гулять так гулять :) Но сначала - прототип у `fgetc()` такой:

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream);
```

Читать из файла в `char` - грубейшая ошибка.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Возвращает количество вхождений слова word в файл.
 * Заполняет массив pos[] позициями слов в файле (не больше max раз).
 * Или под позицией имеется в виду порядковый номер слова? Да пофиг,
 * переделать не проблема, код даже проще станет.
 * Символы-разделители слов задаются аргументом delim.
 */
static size_t find_word(FILE * file, const char * delim, const char * word,
        long * pos, size_t max) {
    size_t words = 0;
    size_t wlen = strlen(word);
    long cpos = 1;

    while (words < max) {
        pos[words++] = 0xDEADBEEF;
    }
    words = 0;

    int c = fgetc(file);
    while (c != EOF && words < max) {
        if (strchr(delim, c)) {
            /* разделитель слов, пропускаем */
            c = fgetc(file);
            cpos++;
            continue;
        }
        /* не разделитель, проверяем на совпадение с первой буквой слова */
        else if (c == *word) {
            /* OK, читаем символы дальше и сравниваем со словом */
            size_t i = 1;
            while (i < wlen) {
                c = fgetc(file);
                cpos++;
                if (c == EOF) {
                    /* конец фильма, выходим */
                    return words;
                }
                if (c != word[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (i == wlen) {
                /*
                 * совпали wlen символов, надо проверить следующий
                 * (если он не разделитель, то не считаем слово)
                 */
                c = fgetc(file);
                cpos++;
                if (c == EOF) {
                    /* конец фильма, слово найдено */
                    pos[words] = cpos;
                    words++;
                    return words;
                }
                if (strchr(delim, c)) {
                    pos[words] = cpos;
                    words++;
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        c = fgetc(file);
        cpos++;
    }

    return words;
}

/*
 * Проверяем:
 */
int main() {
    const char delim[] = " .,;'!?'\"[]{}()\r\n\t";
    const char word[] = "word";
    const char file[] = "file.txt";
    /* Ну... Лонг так лонг, не будем упираться... */
    long pos[16];
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");

    if (!f) {
        perror(file);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Word count: %zu\n",
            find_word(f, delim, word, pos, sizeof(pos) / sizeof(pos[0])));
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я сейчас пережевывать все это буду. Спасибо большое за старания. Но для начала: что за тип в конце `%zu`?

Comment: Это формат для `size_t`.

Comment: Вылазит _unknown conversion type character 'z' in format_ на него.

Comment: Компилятор какой? Если не понимает - можно на `%u` заменить.