# Поиск слова в файле с помощью found

Tags: c++, строки, поиск

Пишу код чтобы он искал введеное слово в файле и возвращал значение (false или true в зависимости от наличия слова), но программа всегда возвращает false в независимости от наличия слова в данном файле. Что не так с кодом?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputword;
    string words;
    cin >> inputword;
    ifstream fin("Words.txt");
    fin >> words;
    istream_iterator<string> eof;
    bool found = find(istream_iterator<string>(fin), eof, inputword) != eof;
    cout << found;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А зачем строчка `fin >> words;`?

Comment: вот [рабочий код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/384839/23044): вот [нашёл](https://ideone.com/Yiv2uh), вот [не нашёл](https://ideone.com/oeW503)