# Проверка нескольких условий одновременно Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл, хочу проверить есть ли в файле например `'Имя' and 'Фамилия' in  line`, то-есть сузить поиск, питон 3 проверяет только последнее условие, как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Имя" in line and "Фамилия" in line
```

Comment: Спасибо, это было так просто..

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрим менее привычные способы сделать то же самое.

```
strings = ['Имя', 'Фамилия']
line = 'Имя, Фамилия, Отчество'
```

Если у вас есть список значений, каждое из которых должно быть `True`, можно использовать [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all). Выражение во внутренних скобках - это генератор. Он перебирает все строки в списке strings и для каждого вычисляет значение `string in line`. Полученные значения формируют новый список.

```
print (all(string in line for string in strings))
```

Можно добавить ещё функциональщины с помощью map. Этот код берёт каждый элемент из списка `strings` и проверяет, что `line.__contains__(этот элемент) == True`. Полученные значения аналогично формируют новый список.

```
print (all(map(line.__contains__, strings)))
```

Comment: Для больших файлов, списков слов можно аналог `grep -Ff words input` использовать, применяя аналог алгоритм Ахо-Корасика, который [может быть заметно эффективней](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/383763/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, самое простое это взять выражение в скобки.

```
('Имя' and 'Фамилия') in  line
```