# Поиск строк в файле

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-2.x

Имеется следующая функция, которая осуществляет поиск подстроки в строке

```
def findPattern(filename, patternList):
    resList = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for pattern in patternList:
                if pattern in line:
                    resList.append(pattern)

    return set(resList)
```

Но она работает построчно. Например, в файле

```
simple string for 
example
```

подстроку `for example` она не найдет. 
Каким образом можно осуществить поиск подстрок, расположенных на разных строках в файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти фразы такие как "for example" в файле, не обращая внимание на вид и количество пробелов между словами, можно нормализировать пробелы в файле и после этого найти строки, которые присутствуют в тексте:

```
def find_phrases(filename, phrases):
    with open(filename) as file:
        text = ' '.join(file.read().split())  # normalize whitespace
    return filter(text.__contains__, phrases) # return phrases themselves
```

Если файл целиком в память не умещается и чтобы не пробегать целый файл заново в поисках каждой фразы, можно регулярные выражения использовать на [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html):

```
import mmap
import re
from contextlib import closing

def find_phrases(filename, phrases):
    # match the longest phrases literally ignoring whitespace
    pattern = '|'.join(['\s+'.join(map(re.escape, p.split()))
                        for p in sorted(phrases, key=len, reverse=True)])
    with open(filename, 'r+b', 0) as f, \
         closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as s:
        return re.findall(pattern, s) # return matched strings from the file
```

Пример:

```
print find_phrases('input.txt', ['simple', 'for example'])
# -> ['simple', 'for\nexample']
```

`mmap` позволяет рассматривать файл как байтовую строку, продолжая работать даже для файлов, которые больше доступной памяти. Регулярные выражения позволяют искать сразу все входные фразы одновременно (`a|b|c` вид regex).

В зависимости от того что конкретно хочется найти: фиксированные строки, учитывая пробел/игнорируя, целые слова/подстроки, с учётом регистра/без, размера файла, количества и размера отдельных строк итд., могут существовать более эффективные строковые алгоритмы, к примеру [алгоритм Ахо-Корасика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA) или с использованием [массивов суффиксов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2), итд.

Использование подобных алгоритмов может быть [разница между целым днём вычислений и всего несколькими минутами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383679/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba#comment383774_383763).

Answer (score 1):

Считываем строки файла, удаляя перенос в конце каждой строки, и объединяем их в одну через пробел. Затем мы можем провести поиск по этой строке, как и требуется:

```
def findPattern(filename, patternList):
    resList = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        text = " ".join([x.rstrip("\n") for x in file.readlines()])
        for pattern in patternList:
            if pattern in text:
                resList.append(pattern)

    return set(resList)
```

Comment: Если целиком в память файл читать и нормализовать пробел: `text = " ".join(file.read().split())`¶ кстати, можно просто `for line in file` без `readlines()`, чтобы по одной строчке за раз читать.

Answer (score 0):

Для небольших файлов попрбуйте так:

```py
def findPatterns(filename, patterns):
    res = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        text = ' '.join(file.read().split())
        for pattern in patterns:
            if pattern in text:
                res.append(pattern)
    return res

>>> findPatterns('file.txt', ['simple', 'for example'])
['simple', 'for example']
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]