# чтение строки без \n

Tags: python, строки, поиск

Привет, используется такой вот кусок кода:

```
stri = fir.readlines()
stri2 = sec.readlines()
count = 0
count2 = 0
while count<i:
    while count2<i2:
        if (str(stri[count]) in str(stri2[count2])):
            newf.write(str(stri2[count2]))
        count2+=1
    count += 1
    count2=0
```

На код

```
print(stri)
```

Код отвечает:

```
['glad\n', 'prog\n', 'end\n', 'test2\n', 'tes222papa\n', 'babasraka\n', 'tetjajoba\n', 'hey']
```

А на код

```
print(stri2)
```

оно отвчеает:

```
['gladdos@mail.ru\n', 'atqqwdqwdfg\n', 'djytjl\n', 'gfqwug[hd\n', 'jr1233tky\n', 'papaqwer@mail.ru']
```

Причем последний **"hey"** может являться и **hey\n** и даже **hey\n\t**
И вообще все элементы так могут являться,в тч и их кол-во.

Как видно stri (1 элемент) имеет общее с stri2 (1 элемент) в виде "glad"
Однако консоль так не считает:

```
>>> a = "test\n"
>>> b = "te\n"
>>> if b in a:
...     print("done")
... 
>>> a = "test"
>>> b = "te"
>>> if b in a:
...     print("done")
... 
done
```

Как исправить ошибку, чтоб строки сравнивались без или с \n ?
Спасибо

Comment: Чтобы найти строки из `second` файла, которые содержат строки из `first` файла: [`grep -Ff first second` (или на Питоне)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Поиск строк в файле](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628508/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [strip()](https://www.dotnetperls.com/strip-python)

**Пример**:

```
inp = ['glad\n', 'prog\n', 'end\n', 'test2\n', 'tes222papa\n', 'babasraka\n', 'tetjajoba\n', 'hey']
out = [i.strip() for i in inp]
print(out)
```

**Результат**:

```
['glad', 'prog', 'end', 'test2', 'tes222papa', 'babasraka', 'tetjajoba', 'hey']
```

Для сравнения без `i.strip()`

**Результат**:

```
['glad\n', 'prog\n', 'end\n', 'test2\n', 'tes222papa\n', 'babasraka\n', 'tetjajoba\n', 'hey']
```