# Поиск соответствующих строк по заданным фразам в текстовом файле

Tags: python

Добрый день! Учусь писать на python. Прошу помочь. Дело в том что есть один csv файл там хранятся тексты и есть слова точнее 5 слов нужно проверить на наличие одного из этих 5 слов в текстах этого файла.

Для примера:
в csv такие тексты:
Добрый день! Меня зовут Джон!
Здравствуйте! Меня зовут Эмма!
Меня зовут Эмили!

Слова: Добрый день, Здравствуйте, Добрый вечер.

мой код:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import unicodecsv as csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

result_read = ['Добрый день' ,'Здравствуйте','Доброе утро','Уважаемый','Уважаемая']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Starting...'

    with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()

    # i = raw_input('Enter response: ')
    # data = [i]
    result = []

    for lines in data:
        #sentences = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, entry.split('.'))
        if result_read in lines: #and len(sentences) > 5 and all([len(x.split()) > 4 for x in sentences]):
            result.append((lines, 'соответствует'))
        else:
            result.append((lines, 'не соответствует'))

    with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
        for r in result:
            f.write(u'{}, {}\n'.format(r[0], r[1]))
    print 'Finished!'
```

Comment: *"Добрый день"* это не одно слово как правило¶ Вы хотите `grep -Ff phrases input.csv` команду реализовать? Какое значение имеет что это csv файл, а не любой другой текстовый файл?

Comment: Так в чем проблема-то? Код не работает? Работает, но не так, как хочется? Выдает ошибку?

Comment: Добрый день! Код работает не корректно, то есть он если видет хоть одно совподение там пишет соответствует, а дальше все остальные не соответствует даже если присутствуют слова приветствии

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти строки, в которых присутствует хотя бы одна из указанных фраз, можно [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) использовать (не тестировал):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import regex  # $ pip install regex

phrases = ['Добрый день' ,'Здравствуйте','Доброе утро','Уважаемый','Уважаемая']
found = re.compile(r'\L<phrases>', phrases=phrases).search

for line in fileinput.input():
    if found(line):
        print(line, end='')
```

Пример:

```
$ ./find-phrases input.csv
```

Это [медленный] аналог: `grep -Ff phrases input.csv` команды.

- [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)
- [Поиск строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628508/23044)