# Как задать переменную, которая бы показывала кол-во совпадающих слов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытался задать переменную, которая бы показывала кол-во обнаруженных совпадающих слов из массива `massive` в файле `example.txt`, но у меня никак это не получается сделать.

```
path='input/example.txt'
massiv = ['Иван', 'Сергей', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Таня'] 

n=len(massiv) # определение размера массива 

def match_doc(): # функция находит совпадения слов из массива massiv в файле example.txt
    count=0
    for i in range(n):
        with open(path) as content:
           print('word found '+massiv[i] if massiv[i] in content.read() else  'This word '+massiv[i]+' not found')
    return i

match_doc()
```

Comment: вы хотите аналог `grep -cFf massive example.txt`? (печатает количество строк из example.txt, которые содержат слова (подстроки) из massive (одно слово на строку)).

Comment: связанный вопрос [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)

Comment: ссылка показывает аналог решения `grep -Fof massive example.txt | sort | uniq -c` то есть выводит количество слов из massive, которые в example.txt присутствуют. Вам какой вариант нужен первый или второй?

Comment: Второй вариант мне больше подходит

Comment: вы хотите частоты слов как по ссылке показано (строки `<слово> <сколько раз встречается>`) или просто сколько слов хоть раз появились вообще как в ответе @gil9red (одно число от 0 до len(massive))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
path = 'input/example.txt'
massiv = ['Иван', 'Сергей', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Таня'] 

n = len(massiv) # определение размера массива 

def match_doc(): # функция находит совпадения слов из массива massiv в файле example.txt
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        with open(path) as content:
           if massiv[i] in content.read():
               count += 1
               print('word found ' + massiv[i])
           else:
               print('This word ' + massiv[i] + ' not found')

    return count

print('found:', match_doc())
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. То что нужно. Все заработало. Вопрос снят

Comment: Пометьте вопрос как правильный