# Проверка строки на соответствие нескольким шаблонам

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть ли возможность проверять строку на соответствие нескольким шаблонам?

```
ExcTC = re.search(r'([TKA]C_)(\S+)(.*)(TS)(.*)(C_TC)', line)
```

но есть еще 2 шаблона, их как-то можно объединить в одной переменной?

Comment: Шаблоны в regex в некоторых случаях можно соиденить через `|` - но тогда не всегда будет понятно какой из сработал.

Comment: Да, так и сделал, спасибо! Думал, есть более элегантный способ. Находя один pattern, второй он забивает в массив пустыми элементами в количестве, равному количеству групп regexp. Делает это по порядку.  Стоит применять, если со всеми тремя pattern нужно проделать одинаковую операцию  (все строки, в которых есть хоть один из 3 шаблонов надо исключить)

Comment: import re
patterns = ['pattern1', 'pattern2']  
text = 'This text includes pattern1 and pattern2'  
for pattern in patterns:  
 find = re.search(pattern, text)  
 print(find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть два регулярных выражения `A` и `B`, то объединённый regex будет:

```
A|B
```

который проверяется слева направо.

Если `A=C|D`, то результат:

```
C|D|B
```

Чтобы помнить, что в задаче `C|D` были одним регулярным выражением, можно их в группу объединить:

```
(?:C|D)|B
```

В общем случае, наличие группы может менять смысл выражения. К примеру, `a|bc` и `(?:a|b)c` (второе срабатывает для `ac`).

Если у вас есть список регулярных выражений:

```
patterns = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, ...]
```

то можно объединить их, используя [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), оборачивая каждое выражение в свою группу с помощью [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) и [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
combined = '|'.join(map('(?:{})'.format, patterns))
```

Comment: Благодарю, но что-то я ничего не понял. Видать, не тот уровень еще. Для чего такие сложности? Зачем map и format?

Comment: @ТрофимВоробьев: если знаете проще способ, опубликуйте свой ответ. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @ТрофимВоробьев опубликуйте в вопросе те два шаблона, про которые написано в вопросе - тогда вам смогут дать более наглядный ответ. Так как вы их не показали - вам дали ответ "в общей форме"

Comment: @jfs Спасибо большое, что подробно расписали. Я новичок - самоучка, не сразу понял вашу идею.

Comment: @nick_n_a И Вам большое спасибо, а по поводу, какой pattern сработал, дам ответ. Он более прост в понимании для таких новичков, как я.

Answer (score 2):

Проверить текст на наличие неограниченного количества шаблонов в нем можно следующим образом. Данный способ позволит также определить, какой из шаблонов сработал.

```
import re

text = "one two three four five"
patterns = ['one', 'two']

for pattern in patterns:
    find = re.search(pattern, text)
    if find:
        print('Found "{}" in "{}"'.format(pattern, text))
    else:
        print('Did not find "{}"'.format(pattern))
```

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что этот способ просматривает text c начала для каждого regex¶ Если нужно знать какой шаблон сработал, то можно именованные группы использовать: `'(?P<x>A)|(?P<y>B)'` -- лучше как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос спросить¶ Если вы фиксированные строки ищите (не общие регулярные выражения), то есть более эффективные алгоритмы: [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)