# Строки. Какой самый быстрые способ поиска вхождения слов в выражение?

Tags: python, строки, производительность

Необходимо проверить входят ли слова из списка `lst` в строку `string`. Представленный ниже код рабочий, но явно не самый оптимальный вариант. И я не уверен что регулярные выражения тоже быстрый способ.

```
string = 'hello world people'
lst = ('foo', 'bar')

r = False
for x in lst:
    if string.find(x) != -1:
        r = True
        break

print('Contains words:', r)
```

Comment: Код в вашем вопросе не учитывает деление на слова, а код в ответе — учитывает. В связи с этим напрашивается уточняющий вопрос: эти слова в `lst` — обязательно отдельные слова или могут быть частью других слов (`abcfooabc` и т.п.)? Если отдельные слова, то что их разделяет — только пробельные символы, или точки-запятые-скобки тоже?

Comment: сравните производительность с `grep -Ff words text` (если выражение в text файл записать, а слова записать в words файл -- одно на строчку). Связанный вопрос: [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044)

Comment: Спасибо учту, но надо в ОС Windows)

Comment: @AlexNasov: grep и рекомендуемый по ссылке ripgrep есть и на Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы проверить присутствует ли в строке `string` хотя бы один элемент из списка `lst` можно разбить строку на слова, преобразовать получившийся список в множество и получить пересечение данного множества с множеством, полученным из списка `lst`:

```
res = bool(set(string.split()) & set(lst))
```

если в результате получится непустой список - это будет показывать, что хотя бы одно слово из списка содержиться в строке.

---

**UPDATE1:**

> Думаю функция деления на слова не так быстра, если на входе будет
>   длинная строка

В качестве примера разобъем полное собрание сочинений А.П.Чехова на слова:

```
In [46]: from pathlib import Path

In [47]: text = Path(r'D:\download\Чехов Антон. Полное собрание сочинений и писем - ModernLib.Ru.txt').read_text()

In [48]: len(text)
Out[48]: 833011

In [49]: %timeit text.split()
19.3 ms ± 196 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

замер скорости проверки на вхождение слов в полном собрании сочинений Чехова:

```
In [50]: %timeit bool(set(text.split()) & set(lst))
35 ms ± 171 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**UPDATE2:** более простой и, похоже, более быстрый способ (скорость будет зависеть от размера списка `lst`):

```
In [55]: %timeit sum(x in text for x in lst)
1.49 ms ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Думаю функция деления на слова не так быстра, если на входе будет длинная строка.

Comment: Прогнав несколько вариантов с входным файлом размером 600Мб и использованием нескольких вариантов 'any' могу скачать, что чаще наименьшее время выполнения показала конструкция с использованием функции .find(x).

Answer (score 1):

Самым быстрым оказался вариант с использованием конструкции `any`, ниже представлен код в котором сравниваются различные варианты поиска, в том, числе с использованием множеств. В качестве входных данных использовался "размноженный" текст на английском языке(~20 Мб), в котором слов из словаря `lst` нет.

```
import re
from time import time

string = ''
with open('1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    string = f.read()

lst = ('garrybaldi', 'megapooper')

t1 = time()
r = False
for x in lst:
    if string.find(x) != -1:
        r = True
        break
t2 = time()
print('Broot:', t2-t1)


t1 = time()
r2 = any(string.find(x) != -1 for x in ('garrybaldi', 'megapooper'))
t2 = time()
print('Any:', t2-t1)

t1 = time()
r_re = True if re.search('(garrybaldi|megapooper)', string) else False
t2 = time()
print('Regex:', t2-t1)

t1 = time()
r_set = bool(set(string.split()) & set(lst))
t2 = time()
print('set:', t2-t1)
```

Результаты:

```
Broot: 0.030079364776611328
Any: 0.028577327728271484
Regex: 0.14287662506103516
set: 0.5278980731964111
```

Comment: попробуйте так: `any(x in string for x in ('garrybaldi', 'megapooper'))`

Comment: точно, спасибо!