# Как вывести только те строки из DataFrame, в которых присутствуют определенные вхождения нужных строк?

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy

Есть Dataframe.
В нем Series c текстовыми полями и даны строчки-ключи.
Нужно вывести те строки Dataframe, в которые есть вхождения строк-ключей

Comment: related: [Pandas filtering for multiple substrings in series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541444/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно фильтровать по регулярному выражению:

```
import re
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(column=["abc", "abba", "ba"]))
strings = "ab", "bc"
pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, strings))
print(df[df.column.str.contains(pattern)])
```

Ожидаемо, результат не содержит `"ba"` строки:

```
  column
0    abc
1   abba
```

Для больших текстов, можно попробовать более эффективные алгоритмы. См. [Поиск повторяющихся строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383679/23044).